# What website people use for vedas?

Tags: support

When someone qoutes verses from vedas, which website it is.
Because I can't find any good translation of the Vedas. Expect ralff t Griffith.

Please give the URL.

Comment: [the correctness of translations](https://i.imgur.com/j7i58VE.jpg)

Comment: @mar this looks like a social networking website not a translation website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very few resources online to read Vedas as such. Even  "Ralff t Griffith" translations are not perfect. They are just like a word meaning-based conversion of Vedic texts. But Vedic texts are not just translations.

You can also refer to these two sites for translation and further reading:

1. **[Online Ved](http://www.onlineved.com/rig-ved/)**
   This site has commentary and remarks for Vedic text along with Sanskrit texts.
2. **[Vedic Heritage](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/rigveda/)**
   This site has videos of the pronunciation of Sanskrit texts and related links for Hindi and English translations along with commentaries and other reference links.

I found the above two sites more useful than Griffith because of the presence of actual texts. Through which you can also understand a bit about the actual translation.